# multiple series with multiple y axis in jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, jqplot

I am using jqplot as my graph model. here i want  plot 2 y axis with time as x axis. i got a example to plot the 2 y axis with single parameters line graph.

Let me explain my case,I am using y1,y2 axis and common x axis with timestamp. For y1 axis let me have s1,s3 series of values and y2 axis let me have s2,s4 series of values. 
here i want plot the graph.

but in my case s1,s3,s4 are plotting  with the reference of  x and y1 axis and s2 alone plotting x with y2 axis,  how to pass the series s1,s3 for y1 ie revenue and s2,s4 for y2 axis ie number of page views.

take this  jsfiddle.net/yRLJF/94/ example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify for each series which axis is related :

```
series: [
  {
   lineWidth: 2,
   yaxis: 'yaxis',
   highlighter: { show: true}
  },
  {
   yaxis: 'y2axis',
   highlighter: { show: true}
  },
  {
   yaxis: 'yaxis',  
  },
  {
   yaxis: 'y2axis',
  }
 ]
```

Please see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/yRLJF/96/)